# Альтернатива swf-файла для HTML5 игр

Tags: flash, canvas, javascript, html5

Добрый день, интересует есть ли какая-то альтернатива передачи сотням и тысячам файлов графики при создании игры на HTML5 по типа swf-файла (который по сути является zip-файлом)?

Есть вариант поместить все изображения на одно большое, но это выглядит.. эмм, мягко говоря не лучшей идеей.

В идеале было бы что бы клево, если бы передавался тот же зип, а на месте распаковывался в изображения, которые кешировал бы браузер.

Answer (score 1):

Если картинки не очень маленькие, то особого снижения нагрузки вы не получите: overhead в виде дополнительных HTTP-заголовков потеряется на фоне основного трафика. А поддержка сервером HTTP 1.1 (а конкретно, keep-alive соединений) ликвидирует задержки на установление тысяч соединений для передачи "тысяч файлов".

Объединение картинок (любое, хоть в zip, хоть в одно изображение) также имеет следующие недостатки.

Во-первых, файлы качаются браузером в несколько потоков, но не более одного потока на файл. Следовательно, один файл качается в один поток, а много файлов - в несколько (количество зависит от браузера, например, хром у меня использует три на домен). Несколько потоков обычно быстрее одного (даже при быстром инете).

Во-вторых, недостаток, связанный с кэшированием. Используя кэширование, вы можете значительно снизить нагрузку на сервер. Использовать кэширование можно как с раздельными картинками, так и с одним объединённым файлом. Но, если одна из картинок обновилась, то клиент может загрузить новую версию только этой картинки, если все картинки раздельно. А если картинки объединены, то клиент вынужден загружать заново весь изменившийся объединённый файл - неэффективно.

Короче, если есть группа сильно маленьких картинок, то можно и объединить - кое-какую экономию можно сделать. Но если картинки не очень маленькие, то вышеуказанные недостатки, по моему мнению, перевешивают преимущества.

Если решите всё-таки объединять, можно воспользоваться какой-либо Flash-библиотекой для архивации (гугл вроде много находит) с привязкой к Javascript. Насколько я знаю, в HTML 5 пока нет никаких возможностей, связанных с обработкой архивов.

Answer (score 0):

Зиповать картинки резона особого нет: на распаковку потратите больше времени. Если это игра, можно часть изображений объединить в спрайты(не все). Если изображения большие - высылать простыню превьюх, а потом кэшировать по два изображения до и после просмотренного(как вконтакте) - это для галереи или для бэкграунда игры.

Если задача только закешировать все подряд(для плавной анимации), то можно по циклу в яваскрипте создать массив рисунков, не прикрепленных к дом-дереву.

Comment: Резон в снижении нагрузки на сервер, вместо того, что бы передать 500 000 файлов 50 клиентам, он может передать только 500. Да их можно даже и не сжимать, что бы не тратить время на разсжатие, просто объединять в один файл (а-ля iso-файл)